# JComboBox - Unable to get the value

Tags: swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I've created Jcombobox in my table as per below.

Code

```
          TableColumn col5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);      
          String[] options = new String[]{"Font Issue","Text Issue","Image Issue","AI Issue","Others"};
          JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox(options);
          JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox(options);
          col5.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo1));
          col5.setCellRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer(combo2));
          col5.setPreferredWidth(150);
          combo2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                String dropDownValue = col5.getCellEditor().getCellEditorValue().toString();
                if(dropDownValue.equalsIgnoreCase("others"))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "alert", "alert", "");
                }
            }
        });
```

There is an error when I try to get the dropwon value.

Error

`local variable col5 is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`.

I even tried like this.

```
String dropDownValue = combo1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

but i get the similiar error

```
local variable combo1 is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: you have to declare it final..

Comment: ehhh ... you are listening to the combo of the _renderer_ to access to value of the _editor_ ? Both is _wrong_ ... as in **incredibly wrong**

Comment: @kleopatra can i change it to listen editing components and access the rendering components? –

Comment: nooo - they are not for external (== outside of JTable's internals) usage. Take a step back and explain _what_ you want to achieve.

Comment: @kleopatra i just want to create a combobox in my Jtable. I used the code and working fine. i just unable to get the selected value and it fixed once i put final keyword as per answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
 TableColumn col5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
```

to

```
 final TableColumn col5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
```

You are defining an anonymous class. To avoid strange side-effects with closures in java variables must be marked as final.

Comment: if i change the TableColumn col5 to final. I'm unable to get the selected drop down list value.

Comment: no error. Since you declare the col5 as final. it taking the drop down default value. I couldnt get the drop selected value in side the action listernersince col5 is already final

Comment: @chinna_82 :S final means that is not going to point to another thing, but can mutate... try defining  `final combo` and inside action listener combo1.getSelectedItem()